# отношение добавить в связную таблицу

Tags: laravel, laravel5

есть таблица User

```
public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(UsersAttributes::class);
    }
```

и UsersAttribute

```
public function user() //Привязываем к модели пользоватиели
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

у них связь 1 к 1

пытаюсь добавить в таблицу UsersAttribute так , но не добавляет

```
$addAttributes = User::attributes()->create(['user_id' => $usercreate->id, 'username' => 'Пользователь', 'phone' => $request->phone]);

Non-static method App\User::attributes() should not be called statically
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attributes` это не статический метод. Вам нужен экземляр класса `User` для того, чтобы создать для него `UsersAttribute`. Например можно вот так:
`User::find(1)->attributes()->create(...)`. Больше информации вот тут https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, забыл указать find(), чтобы получить модель usersattributets через модель users по ключу user_id

```
$addAttributes = User::find($usercreate->id)->attributes()->create(['user_id' => $usercreate->id, 'username' => 'Пользователь', 'phone' => $request->phone]);
```